# syntax error, unexpected ')' foreach laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I try looping variable with foreach in laravel but I get error

> syntax error, unexpected ')'

Here my **controller**

```
public function getAdd()
    {

        $tahun_awal_bgt = 1990;
        $tahun_skr_bgt = date('Y');

        return view('laporan.posisikeuangan_laporan')->with([
            'tahun_awal_bgt' => $tahun_awal_bgt,
            'tahun_skr_bgt' => $tahun_skr_bgt]);
    }
```

This my **views**

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>-- Semua --</option>
      @foreach($tahun_awal_bgt <= $tahun_skr_bgt)
        <option value="{{ $tahun_skr_bgt }}">{{ $tahun_awal_bgt }}</option>
        {{ $tahun_awal_bgt++ }}
      @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
```

I still dont understand where I'am doing wrong, how do I fix this ?

Comment: `@foreach($tahun_awal_bgt <= $tahun_skr_bgt)` this does not seem to be correct. Also, give a little more details about the error.

Comment: I need a confirmation from you. Are you trying to make a select options that shows year from 1990 to 2017 or otherwise?

Comment: I try to make the select options from 2017 to 1990 @WandaIchsanulIsra

Comment: Okay. I already answered your question. Hope it helps @perbatek

Comment: @WandaIchsanulIsra thank you very much

Comment: Is that fixed your problem correctly? @perbatek

Comment: @WandaIchsanulIsra sure that work perfectly

Comment: Great. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use for loop in your case:

```
@for($tahun_awal_bgt = $tahun_awal_bgt; $tahun_awal_bgt <= $tahun_skr_bgt; $tahun_awal_bgt++)
        <option value="{{ $tahun_skr_bgt }}">{{ $tahun_awal_bgt }}</option>

        <!-- No need for $tahun_awal_bgt++ here, i added in for loop  -->

      @endfor
```

Please note that i used @for and @endfor instead of @foreach and @endforeach, further there was no need to do {{ $tahun_awal_bgt++ }} in loop block is I already added it in @for loop declaration.

You should also learn how to use for and foreach loop in php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: its work but begin from 1990 then 2017 not 2017 then 1990

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in thr blade

```
 @foreach($tahun_awal_bgt <= $tahun_skr_bgt)
```

To

```
 @foreach($tahun_awal_bgt as $tahun_skr_bgt)
```

Comment: He needs to stop the loop when $tahun_awal_bgt <= (less than or equal to) $tahun_skr_bgt. i think your code will not work for him.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your confirmation at the comment before, you can follow this code to fix your problem.

```
@for($tahun_skr = $tahun_skr_bgt; $tahun_skr >= $tahun_awal_bgt; $tahun_skr--)
    <option value="{{ $tahun_skr }}">{{ $tahun_skr }}</option>
@endfor
```