# syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get data into bar chart from db but it gives the above error,

code of controller:

```
   public function chart($id)
   {
    $data = File::findOrFail($id);
    $result = \DB::table('importpdfs')
                ->where('Battery','=','Verbal')
                ->orderBy('SAS', 'ASC')
                ->get();
    @foreach ($pdfdata => $data)
      {{ $data->SAS }}
    @endforeach
    return response()->json($result);
  }
```

bladefile:

```
     <div class="container">
          <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        @push('scripts')
        <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
      @endpush
      <script>
        var url = "{{url('importpdfs')}}";
          var Bat = new Array();
          var Sas = new Array();
            //$(document).ready(function(){
              //$.get(url, function(response){
                //response.forEach(function(data){
                  //Bat.push(data.Battery);
                  //Sas.push(data.SAS);
            //});
        let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

          // Global Options
          Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
          Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
          Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';

          let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, 
          polarArea
        data:{
          labels:['Verbal', 'Quantitative', 'Non-Verbal', 'Spatial'],
            datasets:[{
              label:'SAS',
                data:[
                  120,
                  112,
                  121,
                  111,
                  110,
                ],
          //backgroundColor:'green',
          backgroundColor:[
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
          ],
          borderWidth:1,
          borderColor:'#777',
          hoverBorderWidth:1,
          hoverBorderColor:'#000'
        }]
      },
      options:{
        title:{
          display:true,
          text:'Bar Chart',
          fontSize:25
        },
        legend:{
          display:true,
          position:'right',
          labels:{
            fontColor:'#000'
          }
        },
        layout:{
          padding:{
            left:10,
            right:0,
            bottom:0,
            top:0
                }
              },
              tooltips:{
                enabled:true
              }
            }
          });
        </script>
```

how to solve it?

Comment: remove `@` sign from `@foreach ($pdfdata => $data)
      {{ $data->SAS }}
    @endforeach`

Comment: @Sohel0415 That's not solving the issue as `{{ $data->SAS }}` doesn't belong in the controller either. So all three lines need to go.

Comment: @Namoshek yeah, that should be it

Comment: @Namoshek so what should I do

Comment: @foreach ($pdfdata as $data)

Comment: @AliÖzen still same error

Comment: add some dd on it. 
@dd($pdfdata)
@foreach($pdfdata as $data)
@dd($data, $data->SAS)
@endforeach

And find out where is the problem.

Comment: nthing, and in console it says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: there are many errors in your code but let me know where you have defined `$pdfdata`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error, unexpected ')' foreach laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519471/syntax-error-unexpected-foreach-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to put blade PHP in the controller? This should strictly be standard PHP.

Let the front-end handle the data (although more of a pain to implement, it will mean the server has a reduced load when handling the operation).

I would advise you remove the foreach in the controller and pass `$result` back to the front end and handle the foreach there.